# What does the config.xml file do in cordova?

Tags: xml, cordova

What is the role of the config.xml file in Cordova. Does it interact with the Cordova javascript, or is it a set of instructions to Cordova only when it builds.

I am using the "platform specific" development method because I am only targeting iPhones at this point. Once I have completed my build, should I worry about config.xml again?

Answer (score 0):

The config file allows a developer to specify metadata about their application in a non platform specific manner. This metadata will be used by the **PhoneGap command line interface** to create platform specific configuration files e.g. the AndroidManifest.xml for Android apps and the Property List file for iOS apps.

For example, if you enable the camera plugin for your device, your config file will contain the line

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

and this will be converted to

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

in the iOS specific config file.

The PhoneGap command line interface will modify the config.xml file when you add platforms and plugins. So, as long as you use the command line interface you are unlikely to have to edit that information manually if you were to revisit you app to add a new platform.

You may have to revisit it though if you were to change your app's name, description or specify other PhoneGap preferences, whic,h given they are in a state of constant flux, I won't list here.

The [PhoneGap Build](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/configuring_basics.md.html) documentation contains a lot more information about how the config.xml file is used to define cross platform metadata than the PhoneGap documentation.